# Gametracker Scraper discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to script something that shows how many players are on a Server using gametracker. I found this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gametracker-scraper). I successfully can log those information in my terminal but i want to display. So when somebody types `.info` that this information are in the channel.

My Code:

```js
        case 'info':

        const module = require ('gametracker-scraper')

        async function output() {
            let info = await module.get('My Link')
            message.channel.send('Our Server Info:' + info)
        }
            output()
```

The text that is posted in the Channel when you write `.info`:

```
Our Server Info: [object Object]
```

Other **scraper** alternatives are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is outputting "[object Object]" because you're concatenating a string and an object.

If you want to output the actual info, you could loop over the object (with, as an example, a [`for in loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)), like this example:

```js
let infoString = 'Our Server Info:\n';
for (const element in info) {
    infoString += `${element}: ${info[element]}\n`;
}
message.channel.send(infoString);
```

Which would produce something like this:

```js
Our Server Info:
Map: (your map)
Online: (your player count)
// etc...
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to just let some information out. Like for example the players so that they're not shown?

Comment: @IneedHelp I think this might work: `if (element === "name of information to exclude") continue;`

Comment: @IneedHelp I put an answer that could help you. You can use `variable.property` to get the values

Comment: I know that may sound stupid but i wanna know for sure. Is there a way to add more things to the string for example the Name of the Server?

Comment: Can you maybe help me with somenthing else. I wanna build that information into an embed but when i try to do that i keep getting the error `RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.`

Comment: @IneedHelp I'd recommend for that problem you open a new question, because I don't know how to help with the problem you just stated

Answer (score 2):

`info` is an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Trying to concatenate an object with a string will return `"[object Object]"`, unless it has a custom [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method. You can access primitives from that object (using `variable.property` or `variable["property"]`) and it should concatenate properly. Another way, not as readable, is using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). This will turn the object into a string

```js
message.channel.send('Our Server Info:\n' + JSON.stringify(info))
```

Comment: I wanna build that information into an embed but when i try to do that i keep getting the error: `RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.`. What do i need to change so it's gonna work?

Comment: Put the stringify into the second arg (value)

Comment: Is there a way to get ride of the `"` in the result. Heres a [picture](https://gyazo.com/7d71ed9360166ae20b1dd28f79935bef) of how it looks right now

Comment: Do `str.slice(1, str.length)` where `str` is the original string you put there